# Multiple Expand/Collapse TableRow component in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using a Material UI table and trying to expand the `TableRow` inside collapse table but I have a problem. Currently, my list all have collapses but they are linked to one state for "open" so if I open one list, all the other lists open.

What is the best way to keep the collapses separate from each other without having a lot of states for each list.

[image: show image]

Please check the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsetable-2wp59

What am I doing wrong? Could you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move a row with Collapse into separate component and handle open/close logic inside.
Thus every row will have own open state and update function.

Here is your updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsetable-forked-kj8v6

Comment: oh wow...Thanks for your help in solving this problem